# is it possible to run specific function from main.bash while function exists on functions.bash script

Tags: linux, bash, function, shell

is it possible to run specific function from main.bash while function exists on functions.bash script?

example:

we want to activate the function - *get_DATA_OS*  from main.bash

more main.bash

```
#!/bin/bash

.
.
.

get_DATA_OS
```

while *get_DATA_OS* func is on another bash script -  functions.bash

more functions.bash

```
#!/bin/bash


get_DATA_OS ()

{

.
.

}

run_cli ()

{
.
.
}

.
.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can achieve this, just make sure that you include the file where your function is before you use it:

## main.bash

```
#!/bin/bash

source /path/to/file/functions.bash
get_DATA_OS
```

Comment: ok , but how to make un-source when I finished to use the functions script?

Comment: why would you do that ? Source simply means that you include the file so you can use its functions.

Comment: for example - this is craze example but could be  - in case we have function1.bash and inside the main script we have same names of functions so after source on functions1.bash I want to do un source to use the fuction in the main bash ( both func are with te same name )

Comment: you can include your first file and then execute its functions and later in your script import the next file.